# Strange Javax.measure.quantity.Length Bound Mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, jscience

I wrote some code using javax.measure, and when I pulled updated code from our repository, I am getting a Bound Mismatch error whenever I try to use `<Length>` from javax.measure.

Edit The Exact Error Is:

> Bound mismatch: The type Length is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter `<Q extends Quantity>` of the type `BaseUnit<Q>`

I moved the code to a clean workspace and everything was just fine, but for some reason in my main workspace it isn't working.

Any ideas to why this is the case? I'm using eclipse and the code in question is below

```
import javax.measure.Measure;
import javax.measure.quantity.Length;
import javax.measure.unit.BaseUnit;

public class MyUnit{
    BaseUnit<Length> unitType;
    Measure<Length> unitValue;

    public MyUnit(double value, String abbreviation) {
        this.unitType = new BaseUnit<Length>(abbreviation);
        this.unitValue = Measure.valueOf(value, unitType);
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return (double)this.unitValue.getValue();
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return this.unitType.getSymbol();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the exact error that you've seen.

Answer (score 1):

[`Measure<V,Q extends Quantity>`](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/Measure.html) requires *two* type parameters:

- `V` the type of the result returned by `getValue()`.
- `Q` the `Quantity` of the `Unit` returned by `getUnit()`.

As the `MyUnit` constructor specifies `double`, the declaration should be, for example,

```
Measure<Double, Length> unitValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just pulled the whole entire project down from the repository to a clean directory and it fixed the problem, I still have no clue what was causing it.

Comment: Sound like a version control problem; glad you got it working.